# Lemmatization using StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

I found this code which lemmatizes a text.
This text is split into sentences and then tokenized.
And finally the tokens are lemmatized.

My problem is that I don't need to do the steps of `splitting` and `tokenize` because I already did that in my program.
I just want to integrate the step of lemmatization to my program, since I already have a list of words which I must lemmatize.

Here is the program that I want to integrate, without the steps which occur before the lemmatization.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class StanfordLemmatizer {

protected StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

public StanfordLemmatizer() {
    // Create StanfordCoreNLP object properties, with POS tagging
    // (required for lemmatization), and lemmatization
    Properties props;
    props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");

    /*
     * This is a pipeline that takes in a string and returns various analyzed linguistic forms. 
     * The String is tokenized via a tokenizer (such as PTBTokenizerAnnotator), 
     * and then other sequence model style annotation can be used to add things like lemmas, 
     * POS tags, and named entities. These are returned as a list of CoreLabels. 
     * Other analysis components build and store parse trees, dependency graphs, etc. 
     * 
     * This class is designed to apply multiple Annotators to an Annotation. 
     * The idea is that you first build up the pipeline by adding Annotators, 
     * and then you take the objects you wish to annotate and pass them in and 
     * get in return a fully annotated object.
     * 
     *  StanfordCoreNLP loads a lot of models, so you probably
     *  only want to do this once per execution
     */
    this.pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
}

public List<String> lemmatize(String documentText)
{
    List<String> lemmas = new LinkedList<String>();
    // Create an empty Annotation just with the given textd
    Annotation document = new Annotation(documentText);
    // run all Annotators on this text
    this.pipeline.annotate(document);
    // Iterate over all of the sentences found
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
        // Iterate over all tokens in a sentence
        for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
            // Retrieve and add the lemma for each word into the
            // list of lemmas
            lemmas.add(token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class));
        }
    }
    return lemmas;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Starting Stanford Lemmatizer");
   String text = "How could you be seeing into my eyes like open doors? \n"+
            "You led me down into my core where I've became so numb \n"+
            "Without a soul my spirit's sleeping somewhere cold \n"+
            "Until you find it there and led it back home \n"+
            "You woke me up inside \n"+
            "Called my name and saved me from the dark \n"+
            "You have bidden my blood and it ran \n"+
            "Before I would become undone \n"+
            "You saved me from the nothing I've almost become \n"+
            "You were bringing me to life \n"+
            "Now that I knew what I'm without \n"+
            "You can've just left me \n"+
            "You breathed into me and made me real \n"+
            "Frozen inside without your touch \n"+
            "Without your love, darling \n"+
            "Only you are the life among the dead \n"+
            "I've been living a lie, there's nothing inside \n"+
            "You were bringing me to life.";

    StanfordLemmatizer slem = new StanfordLemmatizer();
    System.out.println(slem.lemmatize(text));
```

Answer (score 3):

If the only thing you need is lemmatization then it's better to use simple Sentence.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Sentence;

public List<String> getLemmasList(String text) {
  Sentence sentence = new Sentence(text);
  return lemmas = sentence.lemmas();
}
```

You can also get words, part_of_speech by:

```
 sentence.word(i);
 sentence.posTag(i);
```

Comment: Got this error:
java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find ways to lemmatize using the new changes in Stanford Core NLP but the current answers aren't updated with the new usage of CoreDocument.
I was able to figure it out - To lemmatize now, the following needs to be done:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
CoreDocument cd = new CoreDocument(text);
pipeline.annotate(cd); 
List<String> lemmas=  cd.tokens().stream()
                                 .map(cl -> cl.lemma())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just not tokenize your string, and let it be lemmatized in entirety.

If I understand correctly, you'll need to remove those two steps you've already done from the properties.

```
tokenize, ssplit,
```

Although, it honestly doesn't hurt to leave them in if you already performed those steps. A single String can't be split again.

If you have a list of strings, you can loop over them individually and call the lemmatize method on a single word the same as a sentence. Note: you can easily edit the method to return the one and only lemma string from the list (or try to remove the list from the method altogether)

Comment: No this does not work. "tokenize, ssplit, pos" are required for "lemma"

Comment: @BingRen Read the question? *I don't need to do the steps of splitting and tokenize because I already did that in my program*

Comment: If you remove those two steps, you get an exception: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "pos" requires annotation "TextAnnotation". The usual requirements for this annotator are: tokenize,ssplit
 at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:456)
 at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
 at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:146)
 at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:133)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the language model on your project as your library.
The file can be found in the following link, "http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/"
for English model the file name is "stanford-english-corenlp-models-current.jar". Also available for several languages including 中国, german, arabic etc